# How to write a for-loop that searches names from data.frame in a character vector?

Tags: r, for-loop, match, apply

I have a data.frame with names of football players, for example:

```
names <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
             year=c('Maradona', 'Cruyff', 'Messi', 'Ronaldo', 'Pele', 'Van Basten', 'Diego'))

> names
  id       year
1  1   Maradona
2  2     Cruyff
3  3      Messi
4  4    Ronaldo
5  5       Pele
6  6 Van Basten
7  7      Diego
```

I also have a 6,000 scraped text files, containing stories about these football players. These stories are stored as 6,000 elements in a large vector called `stories`.

Is there a way a loop (or an apply function) can be written that searches for the names of each of the football players. If a match or multiple matches occur, I would like to record the element number and the name(s) of the football player.

For example, consider the following text in `stories[1]`:

```
Diego Armando Maradona (born 30 October 1960) is a retired Argentine 
professional footballer. He has served as a manager and coach at other
clubs as well as the national team of Argentina. Many in the sport,
including football writers, former players, current players and 
football fans, regard Maradona as the greatest football player of all
time. He was joint FIFA Player of the 20th Century
with Pele.
```

The ideal `data.frame` would have the following structure:

```
> outcome
  element    name1 name2
1       1 Maradona  Pele
```

Does somebody know a way to write such a code that results in one data.frame for with information on all football players?

Comment: I would consider a text mining approach like this for example https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31867_8236987cf0a8444e962ccd2aec46d9c3.html

Comment: And in you output file Diego should also be found with one count.

Comment: @Jimbou: you are right. And you have a sharp eye.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it with a loop, but maybe you can do it with an apply function

```
#Make sure you include stringsAsFactors = F or my code won't work
football_names <- data.frame(id=c(1:7), 
                year=c('Maradona', 'Cruyff', 'Messi', 'Ronaldo', 'Pele', 'Van Basten', 'Diego'),stringsAsFactors = F)


outcome <- data.frame(element=football_names$id)

for (i in 1:nrow(football_names)){
  names_in_story <- football_names$year[football_names$year %in% unlist(strsplit(stories[i],split=" "))]

  for (j in 1:length(names_in_story)){
    outcome[i,j+1] <- names_in_story[j]
  }

}

names(outcome) <- c("element",paste0("name",1:(ncol(outcome)-1)))
```

Comment: May I ask you why you use 'football_name$year'?

Comment: I used "football_names" as the name of the data frame instead of just "names" like you had it because there is a `names()` function.  And you named that column "year" which I didn't understand, but I named it that anyway.

Comment: I see, I messed that up. Thanks! I am trying the code now on my real data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't undertsand your question exactly. But you can try to use a string match using a`stringr` function and lapply. 
I assumed that your data `stories` is a list.
The function finds all names you provide into the function as a vector and counts their occurence. The output is again a list.

```
foo <- function(x,y) table(unlist(str_match_all(x,paste0(y,collapse = "|"))))
```

The result

```
res <- lapply(series, foo,names$year)
```

Then you can merge and sum up the data (`rowSums()`) for example like this:

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T, by="Var1"), res)
```